# a button that takes to a new panel

Tags: java

I created a button that is in the main page which when a user clicks on it، it changes the panal ( the main idea is that it changes the background and all whats on the panel and adds new stuff to it ) however i failed!, i also failed in adjusting the location of the button although i tried button.setBounse(..) 
anyhow can someone help me in those two things?

```
public class mainClass {
private static  JButton start;
static BackgroundPanel bp = null;
static JFrame mainf = null;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     mainf = new JFrame ("سين جيم");


    // background

    BufferedImage mFrame = ImageIO.read(new File("B1.png"));
    bp = new BackgroundPanel(mFrame);
    mainf.add(bp);
    bp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    // Hi string 
    JLabel hi = new JLabel ("أهلا وسهلا");
    Font fs = hi.getFont();
    hi.setFont(fs.deriveFont(50f));
    bp.add(hi);

    // button 
    JPanel another =  new JPanel();
    start = new JButton ( " لنبدأ");
    bp.add(start);
    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
              bp.removeAll();
              BufferedImage mFrame2= null;
            try {
                mFrame2 = ImageIO.read(new File("B2.png"));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
              bp = new BackgroundPanel(mFrame2);
              bp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

              JLabel hi1= new JLabel ("worked");
              bp.add(hi1);


          } 
        } );


    // end of frame
    mainf.pack();
    mainf.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Take a look at [using `CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: @Julian L. which set do u mean ? a bit lost, i created a new frame as i ran out of idea, tried deleting and re setting them and did not work. can u show me which set method exactly am suppose to use ?

Comment: Note that the comments here are the *question* comments. If you want to comment on an answer, there is an "add comment" link **under the answer**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to change your main panel you don't have to create a new Frame object and set it's main panel. E.g., you could write a setter for `bp` and invoke this method in your action listener method. If your panel has a different size, you can easily change the frame's size...

Comment: which set do u mean ? a bit lost, i created a new frame as i ran out of idea, tried deleting and re setting them and did not work. can u show me which set method exactly am suppose to use ?

Comment: please check the code above, still did not work thu!

Comment: Please read literature about Swing GUI programming. To set a root panel which should be the main content of your frame, call `mainf.setContentPane(yourActualPanel);`.

Comment: This [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html) should help you.

Comment: which program is the documentation based on ? am using eclipse

Comment: can u show me code wise where to plug mainf.setContentPane(bp); ?

Comment: I fixed the problem, however i still cant manage to set the location correctly although i used JLabel.setLocation(x, y);

Comment: Sure you didn't forget adding the label to the BackgroundPanel object which was set as contentPane? In the code above it is done but check if you didn't remove that.